# How do I query to get the friendly display name of an Azure resourceType?

Tags: c#, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net

I am trying to output some information about Azure resources, and would like to display the same value that the Azure Portal has in the TYPE column for a list of Resources in a Resource Group. This is with the ARM APIs (using C#).

I'm not having a lot of fun finding mappings for this.

ie: Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines shows as "Virtual machine".

or

Microsoft.Sql/server shows as "SQL server"

Does anyone how to query to map resourceTypes into the friendly display names shown in the Azure Portal?

Comment: Hi Dana,
In order for people to assist you, could you please post the code which you have tried along with the actual and expected responses.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following API  for getting the information of a resource group

Resources - List By Resource Group

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/resources?api-version=2019-05-01
```

from SDK, you can refer

```
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.resourcegroupsoperationsextensions.listasync?view=azure-dotnet

 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/listbyresourcegroup
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What I am looking for is the human readable name, not the technical one. The value in the property resourceType would show as "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" instead of "Virtual machine" which is what the portal shows in the TYPE column. Is there an API or Constants file somewhere that maps the technical name with the user friendly value that the portal shows?

Comment: You can use substring(Regex to check ) and take the last word after "/", With the API , you will be able to get the complete type. E.g. Word.Split('/').Last()

Comment: That doesn't seem like a reliable approach. Consider Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases. That will NOT map to "SQL database" as shown in the portal. What API is the portal using to map this?

Comment: I debugged the API code in Portal.azure .com too. In that too response is like microsoft.compute/galleries/images/versions , So what we see in the portal is the derived value in client side,same approach you can take it too. https://management.azure.com/batch?api-version=2015-11-01 was the url , you can observe it too under Azure portal in network tab